# rails polymorphic many-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have these models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizings, as: :categorizable
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizings

class Categorizing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :categorizable, polymorphic: true

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizings
  has_many :categorizables, through: :categorizings
```

How can I get all the companies having a specific category?

I tried

```
Category.find_by_name("fff").companies
```

plus a lot of other solutions but couldn't get it working

Thx!

Comment: I can only imagine the pain linguists will go through seeing this... :)

Comment: How you expect this to work if you don't have companies relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following

```
Category.first.categorizables.where(categorizable_type: 'Company')
```

that would select all the Companies associated with Category using your relationship schema.

Also read some about `has_many :through` association because I think you don't quite get it http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association